# What is the duration and expiry date of the patent?

Tags: expiration

In reference to the patent: [WO2014053910A3](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2014053910A3)

Comment: It’s only an application. It may or may not get granted.

Answer (score 1):

Corresponding application (priority) was first filed in US. Application No. 14/432,431 : [USPTO](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). The application was subsequently abandoned. However there were multiple provisional applications for the same invention by the same applicant.

[WO2014053910A3](http://211.157.104.77:8080/sipo_EN/search/quickSearch.do?method=search) was corresponding PCT application filed for [14/432,431](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). It seems it entered National Phase in [China](https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2014053910A2/en) only. China Application No.    [201380063286](http://211.157.104.77:8080/sipo_EN/search/detail.do?method=view&parm=16b414c21a2f19d11b2c18401bcd1a5f183a19361acb1be11a781c5804f92c231f4e218a22572195236c20482755275723ca24be2221222525702494250d26c0274025822c3f29092a7c29a02d6d2d6f28fa2ed62bd12c892f482c34330947932f5c2c0a2ac731b9333c316c366534e7318235ee337934f1360837f03747371b371a34e231bf38f13b04390c3e0d3f6f39ea3dc63c573d6d3e683e4c26d918c33ffe3c523c273e354334405c47c545774302408e4423458947e84698462746af46ce46da436f47554bcc49784a2d) seems to be pending.

There is [WO2012135600](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2012135600&recNum=21&maxRec=38&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=Pub+Date+Desc&queryString=2012%2F135600&tab=PCTBiblio) **granted in the US as [US9970022B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9970022B2/en) on 05.15.2018 with priority date 03.30.2011 and likely to expire after 10.09.2033(after adding adjustment period of 922 days) if maintenance fees are paid duly**.  National phase entry pending in [China](http://211.157.104.77:8080/sipo_EN/search/detail.do?method=view&parm=16b414c21a2f19d11b2c18401bcd1a5f183a19261acb1be11a781c4806f92e231f5221ba22572195236c20482755275723ca24be2221222525702494250d26c0274025822c3f29092a7c29a02d6d2d6f28fa2ed62bd12c892f482c34330947932f5c2c0a2ac731b9333c316c366534e7318235ee337934f1360837f03747371b371a34e231bf38f13b04390c3e0d3f6f39ea3dc63c573d6d3e683e4c26d918c33ffe3c523c273e354334405c47c545774302408e44234595478846bc462d46ae46c846ba436f47554bcc49784a2d) and also entered in [Thailand](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2012135600&recNum=21&tab=NationalPhase&maxRec=38&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=Pub+Date+Desc&queryString=2012%2F135600) (as per WIPO) . These claim priority to other provisional applications at USPTO.

This list may not be exhaustive.

Comment: If there is a granted patent then link to that. Claims can change dramatically from application to patent.

Comment: Edited and link given for granted patent.

Comment: I edited your link for clarity.

Comment: According to the US Public Pair, US9970022B2 has a total of 922 days of patent term adjustments. This bumps the expiration date to October 9, 2023. You might want to edit your answer to reflect this.